# VHDL Fpga debouncing

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I had some troubles with debouncing on one button, so i searched on Google to find a solution for my debouncing problem.

I found this code:

http://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4980758#DebounceLogicCircuit(withVHDLexample)-TheoryofOperation

Which seem to do the trick, but i am having a hard time understanding the code, and it works.

Could someone clarify how this code works, and how/where i can modify it so i turn on and off an LED.

i tried to change it a bit here

```
LIBRARY ieee;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY debounce IS
  GENERIC(
    counter_size  :  INTEGER := 19); --counter size (19 bits gives 10.5ms with 50MHz clock)
  PORT(
    clk     : IN  STD_LOGIC;  --input clock
    button  : IN  STD_LOGIC;  --input signal to be debounced
    result  : OUT STD_LOGIC; --debounced signal
     LED        : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     Segment: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
     AN: out std_logic
     );
END debounce;

ARCHITECTURE logic OF debounce IS
  SIGNAL flipflops   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0); --input flip flops
  SIGNAL counter_set : STD_LOGIC;                    --sync reset to zero
  SIGNAL counter_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(counter_size DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0'); --counter output
  signal counter_10:            integer range 0 to 9 := 0;
  signal counter_10r:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
BEGIN

  counter_set <= flipflops(0) xor flipflops(1);   --determine when to start/reset counter
  An <= '1';

  PROCESS(clk)
BEGIN
        IF(clk'EVENT and clk = '1') THEN
            flipflops(0) <= button;
            flipflops(1) <= flipflops(0);
                If(counter_set = '1') THEN --reset counter because input is changing
                    counter_out <= (OTHERS => '0');
                ELSIF(counter_out(counter_size) = '0') THEN --stable input time is not yet met
                    counter_out <= counter_out + 1;
            ELSE --stable input time is met
                result <= flipflops(1);
                counter_10 <= counter_10 + 1;
                case counter_10 is 
                    when 0 => counter_10r <= "01000000";
                    when 1 => counter_10r <= "01111001";
                    when 2 => counter_10r <= "00100100";
                    when 3 => counter_10r <= "00110000";
                    when 4 => counter_10r <= "00011001";
                    when 5 => counter_10r <= "00010010";
                    when 6 => counter_10r <= "00000010";
                    when 7 => counter_10r <= "01111000";
                    when 8 => counter_10r <= "00000000";
                    when 9 => counter_10r <= "00010000";
                    when others => counter_10r <= "00000000";
                end case;
                LEd <= conv_std_logic_vector(counter_10,4);
                segment <= counter_10r;

END IF; 
END IF;
END PROCESS;
END logic;
```

But it does not seem to work, the LED is constantly lid...

Comment: "The LED"? The code is designed for a 7-segment display.

Comment: Both segment and LED.. don't mind the segment part.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't identify any specific difficulties, here's a quick run-through. If there are points you still don't understand, ask followup questions in the comments below.

`flipflops` is used to create an edge detector; `counter_set` pulses high every time there's an input transition. *(Note that this is poor design — since `button` is an asynchronous input, there should be at least one more flipflop to reduce the chance of metastability.)*

Every time `counter_set` pulses high, `counter_out` is cleared; otherwise it counts up until the MSB gets set, at which time `result` is set to the same state as `button`.

As a demo, the code increments `counter_10` on every debounced transition (both low-to-high and high-to-low), which then gets decoded for a 7-segment display. In place of this, you could toggle your LED. If you want the LED to only toggle on one edge and not the other, make it conditional on `result`.

Comment: The idea with this code was to make it change the LED state from beeing turned on and turned off. 

First time i press it, should the LED turn on
Next time i press it, it should turn the LED off.